# Listas dentro dataframes

Tags: string, lista, pandas, dataframe

Estoy trabajando con tweets y tengo un dataframe con listas de elementos string:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([('parrot', [], 'tweet'),   
                    ('lion',  ["covid"], 'tweet'),  
                    ('monkey', ["covid", "gripe"] , 'tweet')],  
                  columns=('name_user', 'hashtags', 'full_text'))
```

Quiero generar filtrados según los elementos dentro de la columna "hashtags".

Hay alguna forma de extraer todas las listas que estén vacías o todas las que tengan contenido?

Me gustaría extraer algo así:

```
name_user         hashtag         
parrot             []
```

o algo así

```
name_user         hashtag         
lion              ["covid"]   
monkey            ["covid", "gripe"]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer de 2 forma:

1. Si quieres que el resultado fuese una Serie de pandas:

```py
hashtags = df.hashtags.apply(lambda x: x if x else "" )
print(hashtags)
```

Esto devuelve una serie, pero con valores vacíos en caso no se cumpla la condición.

2. Si quieres que el resultado fuese una lista

```py
hashtags = [x for x in df["hashtags"] if x]
#igualmente lo puedes convertir a una serie 
serie = pd.Series(hashtags)
print(serie)
```

Solo tendrías que cambiar la condición si quieres obtener solo los vacíos.

Comment: Hay algo que no comprendo del todo, la 1 me extrae la lista entera de igual manera que si hiciera df.hashtags

Comment: Nop, si te la extrajera tal cual se te mostraría una lista vacía pero con mi código se te muestra una cadena vacía

Comment: Disculpa estoy tratando de  aprender un poco todo esto de momento :  la 1 tiene el problema de que devuelve la columna entera ya que recorre x pero x es [] por lo que nunca esta vacia. no se como hacer para que cuando x sea solo [] no me lo devuelva.  estoy tratando de encontrar alguna solución sencilla pero talvez deba establecer una función para recorrer cada lista pero no me parece lo mas optimo.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/dfb50b6d8f03755aaa98b3a40f44d8aa

Comment: Una lista vacía tiene un valor *falsy* y una llena un *truthy*

Comment: El segundo método funciona perfectamente, si quieres que sea una serie de pandas solo la conviertes